# Data set size, how many to have a significant result?

Tags: statistical-significance, dataset, sample-size

How many records (at least) should I have for my correlation (pearson/canonical) to be significant.

Comment: This is not clear as to what you want to know.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I have a dataset of 50 records, I applied pearson correlation on them and I have found that there is some correlation between my columns. I just want to know if with just 50 records I can say that this study is valid. Thanks

Comment: @StudentT, I am a newbie in statistics. Can you please explain to me what do you mean by *reverse it* and how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: 1. What you're doing make no sense in statistics. If you have nothing significant, just report it. You should also at least tell us what correction test you're using.

Comment: 2. There're many ways to make your result significant. You can just select a different significant level. Or carefully select a subset dataset.

Comment: @StudentT with 50 records I do have significant results. An online survey were conducted to collect those 50 answers. I just want to know if these records are enough or should I collect more.

Comment: @AlexFirsov many thanks I didn't see this question.